# Formatting chemistry reaction

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, alignment, chemfig, chemistry

This is a draft of the reaction I would like to draw

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage[greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
    \mhchemoptions{layout=stacked}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \schemestart
    (A) \chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-Cl)-=)} \+ 2\chemfig{NH_3}
    \schemestop\\
    \schemestart
    (B) \chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-NO_2)-=)} \+ 2\chemfig{H_2}
    \schemestop
\end{minipage}
}
\noindent\fcolorbox{blue}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-{Triangle[]}] (0,0.75) -- (3,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}\\

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-{Triangle[]}] (0,-0.75) -- (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
}
\noindent\fcolorbox{green}{white}{%
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-NH_2)-=)}
    \schemestop
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In particular, I found problems in creating a space between reaction (A) and reaction (B) without losing their left alignment, and in aligning the arrows from reactions (A) and (B) towards the final product.
I colored the edges of the mini pages only to realize their size.
The tikz documentation is quite scattered, and I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\makebox[2em][l]{(A)}\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-Cl)-=)} \+ 2 \chemfig{@{a}NH_3}
\schemestop

\vspace{4ex}
\schemestart
\makebox[2em][l]{(B)}\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-NO_2)-=)} \+ 2 \chemfig{@{b}H_2}
\schemestop

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\coordinate (A) at ([xshift=2em]a.center);
\coordinate (B) at (A |- b.center);
\path (A) -- (B) node[midway, xshift=12em] (c) {\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-NH_2)-=)}};
\draw[-{Triangle[]}, shorten >=1ex] (A) -- (c.west);
\draw[-{Triangle[]}, shorten >=1ex] (B) -- (c.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Do you mean this alignment?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\makebox[2em][l]{(A)}\chemfig{*6(-(@{a1}-OH)=-=(-Cl)-=)} \+ 2 \chemfig{@{a}NH_3}
\schemestop

\vspace{4ex}
\schemestart
\makebox[2em][l]{(B)}\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(@{b1}-NO_2)-=)} \+ 2 \chemfig{@{b}H_2}
\schemestop

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\coordinate (A) at ([xshift=2em]a.center);
\coordinate (B) at (A |- b.center);
\path (a1) -- (b1) node[midway, xshift=20em] (c) {\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-NH_2)-=)}};
\draw[-{Triangle[]}, shorten >=1ex] (A) -- (c.west);
\draw[-{Triangle[]}, shorten >=1ex] (B) -- (c.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's right, just what I meant to do! Now it remains for me to align reactions (A) and (B). A thousand thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to do something similar with chemfig's "merge" command

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart[-90]
%
\makebox[20pt]{(A)}\chemfig{*6(-(-@{z}OH)=-=(-C\ell)-=)} \+ \chemfig{2N@{a}H_3}
%
\arrow{0}
%
\makebox[20pt]{(B)}\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-NO_2)-=)} \+ \chemfig{2N@{b}H_3}
%
\merge(c1)(c2)--()
%
\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-NH_2)-=[@{c}])}
%
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

OR is possible align the reaction, with a bit more code:

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}
\schemestart[-90]
%
\subscheme{
%
\chemfig{*6(-(-@{z}OH)=-[@{y}]=(-C\ell)-=[@{m}])} \arrow(@{y}--){0}[0,.1]\+ \chemfig{2N@{a}H_3}
%
\arrow(@{m}--){0}[180,.5]\makebox{(A)}
}
%
\arrow{0}
%
\subscheme{
\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-[@{w}]=(-NO_2)-=[@{n}])} \arrow(@{w}--){0}[0,.1]\+ \chemfig{2N@{b}H_3}
%
\arrow(@{n}--){0}[180,.5]\makebox{(B)}
}
%
\merge(c3)(c7)--()
%
\chemfig{*6(-(-OH)=-=(-NH_2)-=[@{c}])}
%
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice! Can we make  (A), (B) and NH_3 vertical aligned in the center of the benzene ring?

Comment: Like this: https://i.imgur.com/Jin8Ha4.jpg with the merge command instead of tikz arrows

Comment: @user3713179  I added code that lines up the reaction, see my edited post above.